# Converting VBS to web form

Tags: forms, vbscript

I need to create a web form that -- 1. checks if a serial number is correct. I have the script that does this in VBScript and I am trying to incorporate that into a form. It is a simple algorithm as shown below (the licence format is 9999-999999):

```
   Dim strID
   Dim ColCSum3

   Dim ChkVal
   Dim InitVal

   strID = InputBox("Please enter the the serial number to verify", "Verify serial")

   If strID = "" Then wscript.Quit
   If mid(strID, 5, 1) <> "-" Or Len(strID) <> 11 Then MsgBox "Invalid number format...", 16, "Input error": wscript.Quit

   InitVal = CLng(Left(strID, 1))
   ChkVal = CLng(Mid(strID, 2, 3))

   ColCSum3 = (2 * CLng(Mid(strID, 6, 1)) + _
               7 * CLng(Mid(strID, 7, 1)) + _ 
               6 * CLng(Mid(strID, 8, 1)) + _ 
               3 * CLng(Mid(strID, 9, 1)) + _ 
               5 * CLng(Mid(strID, 10, 1)) + _ 
               4 * CLng(Mid(strID, 11, 1))) * 3

   If 11 * InitVal + ColCSum3 + 3 = ChkVal Then
       MsgBox strID & " is a valid serial number..", 64, "Validated"
   Else
       MsgBox strID & " is not a valid serial number", 48, "Invalid"
  End If
```

and 2. Once this works, would the key inputed by the user be able to get stored into a database somewhere so that it does not get used again? So I guess the form would also have to check against this field of the database.

The main site is in WordPress but I could set this up as a standalone page if need be. Maybe there is a good WP form plugin that is capable of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you want to validate against re-use, you'll have to store them somewhere.  If you want it to work within WordPress, you'll have to write it in PHP.

Comment: Yeah Jen R I figured as much. Was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction in order to do that.